# Restangular post data sent as json payload not form data

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am trying to post to a car record example

```
Restangular.one('cars', 5).post('bids', {data: 'Some data'}).then(function() {
    $state.go('^');
});
```

or

```
Restangular.one('cars', 5).all('bids').post({data: 'Some data'}).then(function() {
    $state.go('^');
});
```

For some reason the `{data: 'Some data'}` is being sent as a JSON payload instead of POST form parameters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I actually fixed the server side to be able to take a full JSON payload as a request, which I believe is more correct as a resource API.

Comment: Same issue here, any news on this?

Comment: Hi @Ian, basically you need your backend to accept payload data. This can be done it nearly all backend server languages and frameworks I would have thought.

Comment: Yeah, did that myself in the end. Makes sense anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Richard, maybe you should reply to your own question for others having the same issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well if you are using PHP then you can get full json payload like this:

```
$data = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

this $data will contain all the post data you sent through http post.